# Unknown item type 'Layer' arcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript to create an interactive map in a web page. When I try to add a layer with an specific id, doesn't recognize the layer and I receive this error:

[image]

The code to add the layer is:

```
require([
          "esri/Map",
          "esri/views/MapView", // SceneView
          "esri/layers/Layer",
          "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function(Map, MapView, Layer) {
          var map = new Map({
            basemap: "gray" // streets, topo, satellite, gray
          });

          var view = new MapView({
            container: "viewDiv",  // Reference to the DOM node that will contain the view
            map: map,               // References the map object created in step 3
            zoom: 4,  // Sets the zoom level based on level of detail (LOD)
            center: [-58, -15]  // Sets the center point of view in lon/lat
          });

          // Add a layer in the map
          Layer.fromPortalItem({ 
            portalItem: { // autocast as esri/portal/PortalItem
                id: "405b97de934143aebe4784e833258a0f"
            }
          }).then(addLayer).otherwise(rejection);

          // Adds the layer to the map once it loads
          function addLayer(lyr) {
            map.add(lyr);
            alert("Layer added");
          }

          function rejection(err) {
            alert("Layer failed to load: " + err);
          }
});
```

The layer is in the arcgis portal ([layer](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=405b97de934143aebe4784e833258a0f)) with the extension *.lyr*.

Comment: We can't see the layer since it is in Portal. Maybe you need to be signed in for the web map to work?

Comment: How can I put the layer in the Portal?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using the class Layer and not an object of the class. Take a look at the line:

```
function(Map, MapView, Layer) {
...
```

This is telling that you will use 3 classes: Map, MapView and Layer.

You already created 2 objects for Map and MapView:

```
var map = new Map({
...

var view = new MapView({
...
```

But you haven't created any object for Layer. Something like:

```
var lyr = new Layer({
...
```